# Ionic, List populating via search

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am using a backemnd service (parse in this case but that doesn't really matter for this question) and wanted to simply search it. I have a textbox that upon text being entered searches the server and returns an array of matchs.

My next step is to simply display my returned objects nicely in a list. Easy enough with ng-repeat but because the view has already been loaded the UI won't update to reflect the array being loading into the list. Does that make sense?

I was wondering if there was a technique to Refresh the list and show the returned search elements, and hopefully I am not being to greedy here but doing it in a way that looks good and not clunky.

I did a lot of googling with NO luck :( any advice would be amazing.

Comment: put some code..!what hav u done..??

Comment: If I am getting it correct, and because you mentioned Ionic, I believe you are using angular. so, you can keep your list two-way bound to an array in your scope, this array would be empty initially. Once you get the results back from service, push the results to the array, and your list should get refreshed as its two-way binding.

Comment: I am using angular! is angular set to automatically refresh? because in my case.. it isnt refreshing the html part of it.. it appears the same as its initial run

Comment: yes, with Angular, the list should refresh when the scope array you are using in your ng-repeat attribute is filled with the data you get from the backend service. I see @PJDev provided an example below. that should get you going.

Answer (score 0):

Without any code provided it is hard to guess what is wrong. Angular has two-way binding, so view should be updated automatically after changing content of an array. If it's not, it means that you probably did something wrong in your code. I present an example code which should work in this case.

**Controller**

```
angular.module('moduleName')
  .controller('ViewController', ['ViewService', ViewController]);

function ViewController(ViewService) {
    var self = this;

    self.arrayWithData = [];
    self.searchText = "";

    // ---- Public functions ----

    self.searchData = searchData;

    // Function which loads data from service
    function searchData(searchText) {
        ViewService.getData(searchText).then(function(dataResponse) {

            // Clear the array with data
            self.arrayWithData.splice(0);

            // Fill it again with new data from response
            angular.forEach(dataResponse, function(item) {
                self.arrayWithData.push(item);
            });
        });
    }

    // --- Private functions ---

    // Controller initialization
    function _initialize() {
        self.searchData(self.searchText);
    }

    _initialize();
}
```

**View**

```
<div ng-controller="ViewController as view">
    <input type="text" ng-model="view.searchText" />
    <input type="button" value="Search!" ng-click="view.searchData(view.searchText)" />

    <!-- A simple ngRepeat -->
    <div ng-repeat="item in view.arrayWithData">
        <!-- Do what you want with the item -->
    </div>  
</div>
```

**Conclusion**

By using splice() and push() you make sure that reference to your array is not changed. If you are using controllerAs syntax (as in the example), assigning new data with '=' would probably work. However, if you are using $scope to store your data in controller, losing reference to the array is the most probable reason why your code doesn't work.